# Prevent user touches on part of an Android device screen while allowing them elsewhere

Tags: android

Basically what I'm trying to do is prevent users from interacting with part of the screen in Android by covering that area with a transparent View.  Looking at other SO posts, I was able to come up with a solution that partially works.  For example, to cover the left half of the screen I could do this:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();    

WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int mScreenWidth = size.x;
int mScreenHeight = size.y;

View leftBox = new View(mContext);
WindowManager.LayoutParams leftBoxParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
leftBoxParams.height = mScreenHeight;
leftBoxParams.width = mScreenWidth/2;
leftBoxParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
leftBoxParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
leftBoxParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
leftBoxParams.alpha = 0.0f;
leftBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

mWindowManager.addView(leftBox, leftBoxParams);
```

The above works correctly for most cases:  If there is a button on the left side of the screen, the user can't touch it, and a button on the right is still accessible.  However, in the case that the user touches the accessible button on the right while also touching anywhere on the left side of the screen, the button will never receive a click event.  This means that if the user is resting his hand on the left half of the screen, the right side becomes basically unusable.

It's important to note that I'm creating the transparent View within an AsyncTask, and things underneath the overlay may be part of other applications, not just mine.

From the Android developer site, it seems like FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL would be what I'm looking for:

> Window flag: even when this window is focusable (its FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE is not set), allow any pointer events outside of the window to be sent to the windows behind it.

However, neither this flag nor FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE fix the behavior I'm seeing.  Any suggestion about why I'm seeing this behavior or how I might fix it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having a finger down in one location won't fire a click event anywhere else, I think that's true for a lot of apps. Why are you trying to avoid clicking on the left side? Wouldn't it be a lot less work to disable the button?

Comment: @McAdam331 Disabling the button is certainly easier within my own application.  However, this overlay might be covering other applications that I have no control over.  I do realize that having a finger down in one location generally prevents click events from firing elsewhere, I'm just hoping to avoid it in my case.  As to why:  it's a bit complicated for 250 characters, but in general think of my app like a guide that goes through setup steps for other apps with the user, so it wants to prevent the user from touching the wrong thing

Comment: So like a showcase view? I think that's the name I've seen used before.

Comment: It isn't exactly that, but it's a good enough analogy.  The big difference is that a showcase view is a little more gentle than my app is supposed to be.  My app is intended to be used in a business environment where there needs to be as much guarantee as possible that the setup is done correctly, which means I'm trying to make it so that even a chimpanzee touching the screen randomly wouldn't mess it up.

Comment: Well you can always check for monkeys: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey()